# Primefaces Datatable: Checkbox select doesn't assign selected values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5, with a glassfish server 3.1.2. I have a trivia question game that relies on the user to select answers. I have two tables which one is generated based on if it's a multi-select question, or if its mutlipile choice. While my multiple choice data table works beautifully, the other does not. I've followed the example on the show case, and when I select 2 of the table, and hit the next button on the wizard it is in, it deselects what I selected and keeps me on the same page. I made it stay on the same page on any exception, and the exception was a null pointer due to the fact that the "selected answers" where null. Here is my table.

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="multiQuestionTable"
    value="#{triviaQuestionsBean.dataModel}"
    var="answer"
    selection="#{triviaQuestionsBean.selectAnswers}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />

    <p:column>
        #{answer.answer.testAnswer}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The setting and getter:

```
private QuestionAnswers[] selectAnswers;

public QuestionAnswers[] getSelectAnswers() {
    return selectAnswers;
}

public void setSelectAnswers(QuestionAnswers[] selectAnswers) {
    this.selectAnswers = selectAnswers;
}
```

The setter is never called, but the data model that is used works very well for the single select. If that is needed to figure out my issue let me know. Please assist if possible.

public class QuestionAnswersDataModel extends ListDataModel
        implements SelectableDataModel {

```
/**
 * This is the question answers data model used to allow for the sorting,
 * and selection of items in a JSF dataTable. This is the basic no-arg
 * constructor --Important-- This judges the data from the id, so if the ID
 * has not been assigned, there will be unpredictable results.
 *
 */
public QuestionAnswersDataModel() {
}

/**
 * This is the question answers data model used to allow for the sorting,
 * and selection of items in a JSF dataTable. This is the constructor where
 * the list of elements are instantiated. --Important-- This judges the data
 * from the id, so if the ID has not been assigned, there will be
 * unpredictable results.
 *
 * @param data The list of QuestionAnswers to display in the table.
 */
public QuestionAnswersDataModel(List<QuestionAnswers> data) {
    super(data);
}

/**
 * This takes a "row key" and looks through the wrapped data to find the
 * specific QuestionAnswers entity that matches the passed in row key
 *
 * @param rowKey The key to search with
 * @return The QuestionAnswers entity that matches the criteria or null if
 * nothing matches
 */
@Override
public QuestionAnswers getRowData(String rowKey) {

    /**
     * Get the wrapped data (If there was a lot of data you would use a
     * query not just a list)
     */
    List<QuestionAnswers> answers =
            (List<QuestionAnswers>) getWrappedData();

    //for each answer
    for (QuestionAnswers answer : answers) {
        //if the answer's unique identifier matches the row key:
        if (answer.getQuestionAnswersId().toString().equals(rowKey)) {

            //return it
            return answer;
        }
    }

    //if nothing matches return null
    return null;
}

/**
 * This takes a QuestionAnswers entity object and returns a key for the
 * identification of this entity. As this one runs off of the ID of the
 * answer, if nothing is assigned to the value, a null key will be returned.
 *
 * @param answer The answer to generate the key of
 * @return The identifier for this object or null if the ID is null
 */
@Override
public Object getRowKey(QuestionAnswers answer) {
    //if the answer is null, return null
    if (answer == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //else get the answer id
    Long id = answer.getQuestionAnswersId();
    //if it's null return null
    if (id == null) {
        return id;

    }
    //else return the String representation of the id
    return id.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is the `dataModel` an instance of `SelectableDataModel`? If not, you'd need to specify the `rowKey`.

Comment: It is. I added the code for it.